# legend doesn't show - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a problem with adding a legend to my plot. My code below:

```
ggplot(data = dane2, aes(x = iterations, y = powers, color = 'Moc testu')) +
  geom_line(col = 'red')+
  geom_line(data = dane3, aes(x = iterations, y = blad_II_r, color = 'Błąd II rodzaju')
            , color = 'orange')+
  ggtitle('Błąd II rodzaju i moc testu w zależności od ilości iteracji') +
  xlab('iteracja') +
  ylab('') +
  ylim(-0.01, 1) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("Moc testu" = "red", "Błąd II rodzaju" = "orange"))+
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = "Legenda")) +
  theme(legend.position = 'right')
```

The legend doesn't show and I don't know why. Could you help?

I tried to plot with this code and it still doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you remove `name = ""` from `scale_color_manual()`? Would be helpful if you can provide the data you're using: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Remove `col = 'red'` from the first geom_line and `color = 'orange'` from the second.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works without that arguments.